# how to automatic mathbold all capital letters?

Tags: fonts, macros, symbols

Every time I write a capital letter in mathmode I want it in bold.

E.g. 
I want to write 
`$B$ is a matrix and $b$ a scalar`
and not to write `$\mathbf{B}$ is a matrix and $b$ a scalar`
but having the same result:
[image]

How to do it? :D

Comment: It *might* be possible, but are you sure you never want a vector space V?

Comment: Maybe but almost all capital letters in my thesis are being in bold. I guess I could switch off the autobolding at some part of the document and switch on it in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bfletters}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{bfletters}

\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{bfletters}{`Z}

\begin{document}

$ b + B + c + C$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very Thanks :D. Do you know how to make it switchable? in order that at some other point in the document I can write in not bold capital letters in mathmode ?

Comment: @Horsetime leave the top two commands globally but put the declaremathsymbols into a `\newcommand\bfAZ{...}` and put the same in `\newcommand\itAZ{..}` but with `letters` instead of `bfletters` then `\itAZ` will switch back to the normal settings and `\bfAZ` will do the above